# Count number of string objects created

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

i wrote this piece of code to compare `String` and `StringBuffer`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String inputText = "let us learn pig latin";
    usingString(inputText);
    usingStringBuffer(inputText);
}

public static void usingString(String input) {
    String pigLatinText = new String();
    input = input.trim();
    String tokens[] = input.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String temp = tokens[i];
        temp = temp.substring(1) + temp.charAt(0);
        temp += "ay";
        pigLatinText += temp+" ";
    }
    System.out.println("Using String             :"+pigLatinText);
}

public static void usingStringBuffer(String input) {
    String pigLatin = new String();
    input = input.trim();
    String tokens[] = input.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer(tokens[i]);
        temp.append(temp.charAt(0)).deleteCharAt(0);
        temp.append("ay");
        pigLatin += temp+" ";
    }
    System.out.println("Using String Buffer  :"+pigLatin);
}
```

I know `String` + operator internally uses `StringBuilder`'s `append()`. And it creates temporary objects as it is immutable. 
I am trying *to prove that by counting the number of objects that are created* while using `String` and by using `StringBuffer`.
Using **Static variable** to count the number of objects is not going to help me as i cannot modify the `String` class. i found this [link](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue038a.html). It seems promising. but i don't know how to modify the `Object.java` file.
using **`System.currentTimeInMillis()`** before and after doesn't help as this operation is very small. **So my questions are**

1. is there any way to analyze or compare the performance of these classes ?
2. How to count the number of String objects created in a program?

Comment: Netbeans has a `Profile` feature that will allow you to see how many `String`are created.

Answer (score 1):

First of all *concatenation* of Strings is done using `StringBuilder` not `StringBuffer`.

example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "a";
    String s1 = s + "b"; 
}
```

Byte code for `s1=s+"b"`

```
       16: invokevirtual #31   // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
```

Here, You create 3 String Objects "a" and "b" are *String Literals* (which are also String Objects) and they go into the String constants Pool.  `"ab"` will be created during *runtime* using `StringBuilder`.

`StringBuffer` is *thread-safe / synchronized* so it will be slower than `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I have corrected that mistake. My question is not about string buffer and builder.